# Listing domains on a UCC/SAN SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, ucc, certificate

Is there a way to list all domains on an SAN/UCC SSL Certificate (ideally using command line on linux/os x)?

Clearly there must be some way to extract the data, since browsers can do it. Unfortunately, I can see the list but can't cut and paste it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
openssl x509 -text < $CERT_FILE

#=>

. . .
                DNS: . . .
. . .
```

where `$CERT_FILE` can have either the `.pem` or `.crt` extension.

Shell functions for viewing cert. files and checking that a cert. & key file match can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/danpritts/2d596b8c01828e9f09329fa741d8838d).

Comment: For posterity, this is the full command I used, since I was doing it for another server: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.org:443 | openssl x509 -text`

Comment: To get a clean space delimited list of domains you can pass it through grep and sed like so `openssl x509 -text < $CRT | grep 'DNS:' | sed 's/\s*DNS:\([a-z0-9.\-]*\)[,\s]\?/\1 /g'`

Comment: You don't need the `grep`. `sed` can do the selecting for you: `openssl x509 -text < $CRT | sed -n 's/\s*DNS:\([a-z0-9.\-]*\)[,\s]\?/\1 /gp'`

Answer (score 17):

You can list the domains with this command (tested on linux):

```
cat cert.pem | openssl x509 -text | grep DNS
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to *see* the SANs, `grep DNS:` is the obvious solution.

If you want to have a cleaner list to process further, you can use this Perl regex to extract just the names : `@names=/\sDNS:([^\s,]+)/g`

For example:

```
true | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 2>/dev/null \
| openssl x509 -noout -text \
| perl -l -0777 -ne '@names=/\bDNS:([^\s,]+)/g; print join("\n", sort @names);'
```

Which would output this:

```
example.com
example.edu
example.net
example.org
www.example.com
www.example.edu
www.example.net
www.example.org
```

So you could pipe that to `while read name; do echo "processing $name ..."; done` etc.

Or for a comma-separated list on one line, replace `join("\n",` with `join(",",`

(The `-0777` switch for perl makes it read the whole input at once instead of line by line)

Answer (score 1):

if you'd like to limit dependencies to openssl, grep, sed and tr and still have easily parseable/iterable output:

- **space** separated list:

  ```
  $ openssl x509 -text -in cert.pem | grep DNS | sed s/DNS://g | tr -d ' ' | tr , ' '
  ```

  *output*:

  ```
  example.com example.org www.example.com www.example.org
  ```
- **newline** separated list:

  ```
  $ openssl x509 -text -in cert.pem | grep DNS | sed s/DNS://g | tr -d ' ' | tr , \\n
  ```

  *output*:

  ```
  example.com
  example.org
  www.example.com
  www.example.org
  ```
- **comma** separated list:

  ```
  $ openssl x509 -text -in cert.pem | grep DNS | sed s/DNS://g | tr -d ' '
  ```

  *output*:

  ```
  example.com,example.org,www.example.com,www.example.org
  ```

**what's going on here?**

- `openssl x509 -text -in cert.pem` produces human readable cert information
- `grep DNS` extracts lines containing the string: `DNS`
- `sed s/DNS://g` removes all occurrences of: `DNS:`
- `tr -d ' '` removes all *space* characters
- `tr , ' '` replaces all *coma* characters with a *space* character
- `tr , \\n` replaces all *coma* characters with a *newline* character
- `|` the *pipe* operator passes standard output from the command preceding the pipe to standard input of the command following it

Comment: The `grep` and `tr` commands are unnecessary if you already have an `sed` process running in your pipe. `sed` can do everything they can.

Answer (score 0):

This will show all Alternative domains in certificate (needed by all browsers today)

```
openssl x509 -text -noout < fullchain.pem | grep DNS
```

The answer will be like this

```
DNS:*.example.ru, DNS:example.ru
```